# Phone Interview Constantly Rescheduled

Tags: interviewing

Without getting into details, what would you do if somebody who is supposed to conduct a phone interview with you does not pick up the phone 3 days in a row? We rescheduled after the first two days, but after calling today, leaving a voicemail, and leaving an email indicating other days I'm available, I still have not heard back.

I hope this does not mean I am disqualified from the position I am interested in.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: strange behaviour. Is it a big company ?

Comment: As hard as it would be to not take this personally, I would instead try assume that this person must be extremely busy.

Comment: Odd, but not unheard of.  Wait a few days and try again.  You haven't lost the opportunity until you hear "no".

Comment: "*What would you do?*" is not a good question for this site, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: "3 days in a row" is probably a distraction. From your description you've rescheduled once, and now there is one no show, which is not nearly so dire as your headline "constantly rescheduled". Maybe this person is out unexpectedly for a few days. Leaving a message is your best course of action "I was expecting our telephone call today but there was no answer. Looking forward to reschedule for a time when you're available."

Answer (score 4):

I remember I saw a case a few months ago, I worked in a company with many "flexible" policies, they were interviewing a girl for a software engineer position. Anyway, the point is my former boss kept rescheduling her interviews, she came 2 times to the office, waited for 30mins and my boss did not meet her.

So the 3rd time they called she said that is amazing how they can think she would want the job since in the interview phase they showed her that the company had no punctuality and respect towards a new employee.

Is funny because when we are looking for job, we kind of miss to see this kind of things, early behaviour tells a lot about the work environment.

Comment: I think the last sentence _early behaviour tells a lot about the work environment_ answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "constantly rescheduling" and "not picking up the phone in 3 days".

I can imagine the first happening when scheduling fails completely, during emergencies. However, "rescheduling" would mean that you are notified of the situation and that the interview has to happen at another time.

"Not picking up" can have different reasons, too. The following come to mind:

- The company is small and NotPickingUp, the only person knowing about you or responsible for/able to conduct the interview, is not available. I would call the company, saying I'm trying to reach NotPickingUp, maybe there's another way to reach NPU or somebody else to talk to?
- The company is "chaotic", whether "neutral" or "evil" is uncertain. Working in such an environment is not for everybody.
- NotPickingUp does not respect you. If NPU is "just somebody in HR", you might be able to deal with it, if NPU is someone you actually have to work with or worse, to work under, steer clear.

Personally, I'd try to talk to somebody else in the company first and use that information to make a decision.

Comment: "Chaotic good" is an option, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would see this as nonsense and keep looking for a job elsewhere. It might be just one incompetent person, it might be a crappy company, it might be a bunch of things, but wasting my time 3 times is more than enough to have me moving on in another direction.